# How can I link to a Google Maps directions url with the user's location already plugged in?

Tags: google-maps

I was browsing [Foursquare](https://foursquare.com/v/bark-hot-dogs/4a81a364f964a5201bf71fe3) recently and they have this neat feature where you can click "Bigger Map" on their map, and it plugs your location in to Google Maps directions to the venue. I was wondering how I could replicate the functionality. (A high level overview is sufficient, I just can't seem to find it in the docs.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not in the docs because it's not a Maps function. If you're talking about the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/), which is what Foursquare uses, they're detecting position using your device. I'm guessing for browser operations, they're using HTML5 geolocation. Here's a demo of just plain geolocation: http://html5demos.com/geo. That will ask the user to share their location with the app. Once you have that, you plug it into the [Google Maps API Directions Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/directions.html).

Comment: Any idea how they get the little Bigger Map button?

Comment: You mean the zoom control? That's the default zoom control, it automatically adjusts down when you shrink the map. But you can also adjust then yourself: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#ControlOptions

Comment: Er, I mean the button in the top right of the map that says "Bigger Map". http://i.imgur.com/wS8zN.png (The one that links you to maps.google)

Comment: Oh, well they just create a link to maps.google.com that goes to coordinates. You can check out the link structure, but it is subject to change so you can't rely on it always being the same.